# Spring Boot CRUD + Hibernate + JSP/JSON - Can´t put it all together

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, annotations

I've been trying to learn Spring for the last three weeks while doing some simple exercise, but even after reading at least 15 different tutorials and reading a lot of StackOverflow answers i can not make this work:

I want to make a 'simple' application that has the following characteristics:

- Be able to give a response with a JSP page with some css and js (in external files) when browsing to `/carsweb`;
- Be able to return a JSON when browsing to `/carsjson`. This response has to be a list of entities "Car";
- Save a new Car on DB when we call `/newcar` (Car comes as JSON in request body);
- Able to retrieve and save Cars from a MySQL database using Hibernate (user/password on `application.properties` file);
- All of this only using Spring annotations, if possible no XML for configuration.

I am able to do pretty much everything, but i can't put it all together. Here's the current state I am at:

[image: Source Packages]

**SpringBootWebApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }    
}
```

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.facundo")
public class AppConfig {

}
```

**HibernateConfiguration**

```
package com.facundo.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.facundo.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.mkyong.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }       
}
```

**WelcomeController**

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/carsweb", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloHtml(Model model) {
        return "welcome2";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/newcar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void postCustomer(@RequestBody Car modelo) {
        carService.save(modelo);
    }
}
```

**CarDaoImpl**

```
@Repository
public class CarDaoImpl implements CarDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void save(Car modelo) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(modelo);
    }        
}
```

**CarPruebaImpl**

```
@Service("prubaService")
@Transactional
public class CarPruebaImpl implements CarService{
    @Autowired
    private CarDao modeloDao;

    @Override
    public void save(Car modelo) {
        modeloDao.save(modelo);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-web-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</description>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistencia -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/websystique
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = MWtqKDeS4I
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
```

So, this is the error that shows when i execute

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

on project folder:

> BeanCreationException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'welcomeController': Uns
>       atisfied dependency expressed through field 'servicioPrueba'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Unsa
>       tisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'carPruebaImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through fiel
>       d 'modeloDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean
>        with name 'carDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.spring
>       framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path reso
>       urce [com/facundo/configuration/HibernateConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is jav
>       a.lang.AbstractMethodError

Which I think can be reduced to:

> Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory'

Finally, i want to say that i THINK that the problem is in some configuration where @ComponentScan doesn't find my files or something like that.
Sure there's a lot to improve so if you tell me what parts are really wrong please do it.
Anyways, thanks beforehand.

Comment: Try the following: Move your `SpringBootWebApplication` class outside the package, in order to be on the root package of your application. There is no need to have an `AppConfig` and `HibernateConfiguration`, combine them into one Configuration class and moved it outside the package along with `SpringBootWebApplication` class to reside in the root package. In your new Configuartion class, there will be no need to add `@ComponentScan`, as `@SpringBootApplication` will already include that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is what i did.

Removed whole configuration package (no more HibernateConfig.java and AppConfig.java)

Changed **pom.xml** to only have:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

And changed **application.properties** to:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/arquitectura
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=MWtqKDeS4I
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE 

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

This now works because Springs starter-web is already configured to return jsp AND JSON by default (based on method return type: String for JSP and ResponseEntity for JSON), and starter-jps also has everything to work with MySQL if you only change (in DAO classes)

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

...

sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(object);
```

to

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

...

entityManager.persist(object);
```